# Paradox of nesting black holes and release of energy

Tags: gravity, black-holes, relativity, potential-energy

By dumping a gas cloud into a small black hole, I can produce radiation energy, this is how quasars produce energy.

By dumping the previous black hole, with the gas cloud inside, into a black hole, I can produce gravity wave energy.

By dumping the previous black hole, with fist black hole and the gas cloud inside, into a black hole, I can produce some more gravity wave energy.

If I put the previous black hole, containing all the things that in contains, into a cold place, I can produce Hawking radiation energy.

Was that not too much energy that I produced there?

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem. Theoretically small BH could be used as means to completly convert mass into Hawking radiation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the energy properly. One way to do this is to look at an object from a great distance, and say that if it's gravitational field looks like it is due to a point mass $M$, then we'll assign that object a mass "m". This mass  is equivalent to an amount of energy $m c^2$, of course. Now, the object could be a gas cloud, a planet, or just radiation.

Consider the gravitational field of your black hole as viewed from a great distance, as you are throwing some mass $m$ into a black hole (which has mass $M$). What happens is that some part of $m' \le m$ ends up inside the black hole, while the rest escapes. By measuring the gravitational field from a distance, you would say that there is initially some object with mass $m+M$, and finally some object with mass $M+m' \le M + m$. Now, not all of that ends up falling into the black hole (some of it ends up in orbit). In any case, the asymptotic "mass" of the gravitationally bound system only increases by as much as you manage to put into it, so there is no energy being produced.